# Can Java class source file be referred from Matlab?

Tags: java, matlab, compiler-construction, compilation

When we refer to a `.jar` archive there can be problems with versions.

But is it possible to refer a source file to be compiled by Matlab?

Does something like that exist?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

just try type !javac  in the matlab command window  
It looks the same as you use in the system console